# Scope of an inside-parenthesis declared object

Tags: c++, scope

If I declare an object like this:

```
void main()
{
    myclass objectA(anotherclass(true,true,0));
}
```

i.e. I create an objectA and another object "anotherclass" by directly calling the latter's constructor, what is "anotherclass"'s scope?

Does it get destructed only when main() finishes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The temporary gets destructed at the end of the full expression that contains it, i.e. when the call to the constructor of `myclass` returns.

Per Paragraph 12.2/3 of the C++11 Standard:

> **Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step
>   in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created**. This is true
>   even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception. The value computations and side effects of destroying
>   a temporary object are associated only with the full-expression, not with any specific subexpression.

For this reason, if `myclass`'s constructor takes an argument of type `anotherClass` by *reference* (either lvalue reference to `const` or rvalue reference), it shall not store it for future use, because it will be dangling if a temporary is passed, and dereferencing it would be Undefined Behavior.

It is only `objectA` that goes out of scope and gets destroyed when returning from the `main()` function.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you where did you study C++ and C++11 in such an insightful way?

Comment: @JohnnyPauling: Well, I guess by spending quite some time here on SO in the last three months :) It's the best place where to learn.

Comment: I agree with you and that's why I ask so many questions, although many of them are just plain stupid. Thanks to guys like you I keep learning! Thank you!

Comment: @JohnnyPauling Go to the C++ tag, order by votes, and start reading. That's how I did it. It led me to tonnes of articles and books and such. Then you get really interested and start reading the standard and suddenly your mind explodes.

Comment: @JohnnyPauling: Don't worry about "stupid" questions, there are no stupid questions as long as you really want to learn and if you are ready to put some efforts.

Answer (score 2):

The `anotherclass` object doesn't have a scope. Scope is a property of names, not of objects, and this object is not named. It's just a temporary object and will be destroyed at the end of the full expression.

Here's the definition of scope (§3.3.1):

> In general, each particular name is valid only within some possibly discontiguous
>   portion of program text called its *scope*.

Comment: Hmm. So how would you rephrase something like "the object gets destroyed when it becomes out of scope" which I think is a common way of expresseing the end of an objects lifetime?

Comment: @Roddy Well that's true for many objects. Objects that are named and have automatic storage duration are destroyed when their names go out of scope. "When the object goes out of scope" is just a quicker way of saying that. The real definition for the end of an object's lifetime is, informally, when it's destructor starts.