# Does this pattern work in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-analysis, c++98, prefast

I'm running PREfast static code analysis on my our projects, and it is giving me C6001 'using uninitialized memory' errors for this pattern:

```
// AutoSelectGDIObject is a class
if (AutoSelectGDIObject & select_image = AutoSelectGDIObject(hDCImgSource, hBmp))
{
   // use hDCImgSource knowing that hBmp is selected into it
}
// now we are guaranteed that hDCImgSource has had hBmp removed and its previous bmp re-selected into itself
```

The trick I'm trying to exploit is to allow the scoping of select_image to just the if-expression (i.e. if (condition) { expression-block = lifetime of condition variable }.

VS has happily compiled (and presumably run this) for quite some time.  I haven't single stepped code like this in a long time, but as far as I can tell, it only enters the if block if select_image's operator bool() returns true, and it destroys the instance of select_image upon exiting that if block.

Is PREfast wrong?  Or is there something subtle here that makes my above code and assumptions incorrect?

Comment: Does `AutoSelectGDIObejct()` return a reference?

Comment: `AutoSelectGDIObejct` is a class.  I'm using a reference to get around the fact that C++ won't allow me to just use `if (AutoSelectGDIObject select_image(...))` <- doesn't compile :(

Comment: It shouldn't. Here is the reason:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580903/scope-of-an-inside-parenthesis-declared-object

Comment: @Mordachai: Could you please edit your question and specify that `AutoSelectGDIObject` is a class type, and not a function pointer as some may assume?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is PREfast wrong? Or is there something subtle here that makes my above code and assumptions incorrect?

That code is invalid C++, but VC compiles it because it allows, as a documented extension, binding lvalue references to non `const`-qualified types to temporaries.

This is a silly extension, in my opinion. According to the C++ Standard, temporaries can only be bound lvalue references to `const` or to rvalue references (and in this case, their lifetime is extended beyond the end of the full-expression that creates them).

Therefore, your `if` statement should be:

```
if (AutoSelectGDIObject const& select_image = 
//                      ^^^^^
                               AutoSelectGDIObject(hDCImgSource, hBmp))
```

See, for instance, this [**live example**](http://ideone.com/MU2q6w).

Notice, however, that *you should not need to use references* at all here. In other words, the following `if` statement is also valid, and expresses your intention better than creating a temporary bound to an lvalue reference to `const`:

```
if (AutoSelectGDIObject select_image = AutoSelectGDIObject(hDCImgSource, hBmp))
```

See, for instance, this [**live example**](http://ideone.com/l9dupk). Besides, the above would also allow you to *modify* `select_image`, while the reference to `const` will not.

Comment: AutoSelectGDIObject seems to be the name of a class here.

Comment: Okay - good to know.  And with the change to const&, you're saying that the code is valid (i.e. that the if-condition will eval to true IFF select_image.operator bool() is true?)

Comment: @Mordachai: It is valid, yes. See, for instance, [this example](http://ideone.com/MU2q6w).

Comment: @AndyProwl I choose the const & because it guarantees that no copies are made.  The AutoSelectGDIObject is non-copyable.  It could be made copyable, but that's just machinery in order to satisfy a certain C++ style, rather than actually more expressive or even more correct (under the hood, it would have to avoid actually don't things in the case of a copy - it would be a hand-off operation, which in general doesn't make sense for such a class).  C++11 makes it possible to do that correctly, but again, for what gain?

Comment: @Mordachai : `if (AutoSelectGDIObject&& select_image = AutoSelectGDIObject(hDCImgSource, hBmp))` would be valid as well, but it's a moot point, as `if (AutoSelectGDIObject select_image = AutoSelectGDIObject(hDCImgSource, hBmp))` would perform a move, not a copy (and that move is almost guaranteed to be elided anyway).